# Obtaining an url with an argument from Play

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

This works well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".class1" ).click(function() {
      window.location.href = "@routes.MyController.index()"; //OK
  })
</script>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".class1" ).click(function() {
    window.location.href = "@routes.MyController.show(_: Int)" + getCurrentIdFromHiddenField();
  });
</script>
```

because `"@routes.MyController.show(_: Int)"` returns a partially applied function.

I don't want to hard-code the `url`, I want to **obtain** it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Play's Javascript Router: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting

```
jsRoutes.controllers.MyController.show(getCurrentIdFromHiddenField())
```

You'll have to generate the `jsRoutes` object, instructions are in the documentation.